# IEx.pry for debugging Argument error :erlang.binary_to_integer

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

As I was playing with a Phoenix starter example found here https://github.com/ryanswapp/react-phoenix-starter-template, I ran into this error which I'm having a hard time debugging.

```
Compiled web/connection.ex
[info] OPTIONS /api/v1/current_user
[info] Sent 204 in 74µs
Compiled web/connection.ex
[info] GET /api/v1/current_user
[info] Sent 500 in 23ms
[error] #PID<0.418.0> running ReactPhoenix.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /api/v1/current_user?jwt=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJVc2VyOmMyZDBmZGQ5LWJkNTUtNDJkNS1iMmJlLTAzYjRkNThkOTg0YyIsInBlbSI6e30sImp0aSI6IjAxZGIxNjQ2LTZmZGEtNGI3Yy04YTI1LTRhZWFhYjAzMjE0NiIsImlzcyI6IlJlYWN0UGhvZW5peCIsImlhdCI6MTQ1NDI1MjE4NCwiZXhwIjoxNDU0NTExMzg0LCJhdWQiOiJ0b2tlbiJ9.YiGd-r2g7w7DiAvicq2C0uqhrwM4ZnUXRlnLg53GLag
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) argument error
        :erlang.binary_to_integer("c2d0fdd9-bd55-42d5-b2be-03b4d58d984c")
        (react_phoenix) lib/react_phoenix/guardian_serializer.ex:10: ReactPhoenix.GuardianSerializer.from_token/1
        lib/guardian/plug/load_resource.ex:27: Guardian.Plug.LoadResource.call/2 
        (react_phoenix) web/router.ex:13: ReactPhoenix.Router.api/2
        (react_phoenix) web/router.ex:1: ReactPhoenix.Router.match/4
        (react_phoenix) web/router.ex:1: ReactPhoenix.Router.do_call/2
        (react_phoenix) lib/react_phoenix/endpoint.ex:1: ReactPhoenix.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
        (react_phoenix) lib/plug/debugger.ex:93: ReactPhoenix.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (react_phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:34: ReactPhoenix.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

The module the error message is pointing to is the following. I tried IEx.pry (as shown in the commented-out code) but it won't suspend the code for inspection even though the server was started via iex -S mix phoenix.server.

```
defmodule ReactPhoenix.GuardianSerializer do
require IEx
  @behaviour Guardian.Serializer

  alias ReactPhoenix.Repo
  alias ReactPhoenix.User

  def for_token(user = %User{}), do: { :ok, "User:#{user.id}" }
  def for_token(_), do: { :error, "Unknown resource type" }

  def from_token("User:" <> id), do: { :ok, Repo.get(User, String.to_integer(id)) }   # This is line 10

  #def from_token("User:" <> id), do
  #  IEx.pry
  #  IO.inspect id
  #  { :ok, Repo.get(User, String.to_integer(id)) }
  #  end

  def from_token(_), do: { :error, "Unknown resource type" }
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(react_phoenix) lib/react_phoenix/guardian_serializer.ex:10: ReactPhoenix.GuardianSerializer.from_token/1
```

**EDIT: I just realized I'm silly and read this groggily. In reality it looks like youre coercing a string (the UUID) to an integer, and that will never work because its a not an integer representation of a string. Comment if you havent figured it out or hit me up on slack and I'll help you debug further if needed, though.**

This line appears to indicate that at this point you are utilizing a Char list when you should be using a string, or vice versa. In Elixir `"` strings are considered binaries, while `'` are considered char lists.

```
String.to_char_list
```

And

```
String.to_string
```

Should be able to help you out and convert it where referenced above. If you drop IEx.pry before that line you should be able to drop in and test it.